# ScriptContext of rhino throws exception when used for any JavaScript Date function

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

If I use try to directly evaluate javascript Date function , it works well as:

```
ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = m.getEngineByName("rhino"); 
String  script = "new Date().getUTCMonth()"; 
System.out.println(engine.eval(script));
```

However if I try to use the ScriptContext object, Then I get an exception on eval method .
following is the code snippet

```
 ScriptContext context1 = new SimpleScriptContext();
 context1.setAttribute("temp", new Date(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
 String scriptUtcMonth = "temp.getUTCMonth()";
 System.out.println(engine.eval(scriptUtcMonth,context1));
```

The exception is :

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getUTCMonth in object Thu Nov 26 13:54:01 IST 2015. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:184)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:198)
    at test.class1.main(class1.java:40)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getUTCMonth in object Thu Nov 26 13:54:01 IST 2015. (<Unknown source>#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3783)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2251)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:83)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_source__11._c_script_0(<Unknown source>:1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_source__11.call(<Unknown source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_source__11.call(<Unknown source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_source__11.exec(<Unknown source>)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1110)
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:172)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: A `java.util.Date` is not automatically converted to a JavaScript `Date`. All objects passed from Java to JavaScript is accessed directly, so it stays a `java.util.Date`, and `java.util.Date` doesn't have a `getUTCMonth()` method.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I understand your point. Then what is the possble way of  evaluating a javascript Date function using rhino.

Comment: Simplest is doing it in JavaScript: `new Date(temp.getTime()).getUTCMonth()`. Tested on Nashorn, should work same on Rhino.

Comment: That worked for me .. thanks Andreas..:)